# SQL query with two self-joins - is there a better way

Tags: sql, self-join

could you help with this query please.

Table structure is as folllows:

### PropertyOwner

- Number (primary key)
- PropertyId (primary key)
- OwnerId

### Property

- PropertyId (primary key)
- LoanId (primary key)

Now, if I have a LoanId, how can I find all properties of property ownerId's who have taken the given LoanId?

I am having the below now but it looks awkward:

```
Select po.OwnerId, po.PropertyId
from Property
join PropertyOwner po on po.PropertyId= Property.PropertyId
join PropertyOwner po2 on po2.OwnerId = po.OwnerId 
join Property pp on po2.PropertyId= pp.PropertyId and pp.LoanId = @_givenLoanId
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the problem with this query?

Comment: Its not clear what problem you are trying to solve. Are you looking for a simpler query?

Comment: Why iis LoanId part of the primary key of the Property table?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Yes, I am looking for a simpler query. LoanId is part of the key because there may be more than one loan on the same property.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for both tables and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: (The property table probably should be called PropertyLoans or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists comes to mind as being a more direct interpretation of what you are doing:

```
Select po.OwnerId, po.PropertyId
from PropertyOwner po
where exists (select 1
              from Property p2 join
                   PropertyOwner po2
                   on p2.PropertyId = po2.PropertyId
              where po2.OwnerId = po.OwnerId and
                    p2.LoanId = @_givenLoanId
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT OwnerId, PropertyId
FROM PropertyOwner
WHERE OwnerId IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT o.OwnerId
    FROM Property p 
    JOIN PropertyOwner o
        ON o.PropertyId = p.PropertyId
    WHERE LoanId = @_givenLoanId
);
```